# Can a corrupted image/video become a XSS vector?

Tags: xss, html, file-upload

Let's suppose that I allow users to upload an image or a video. Obviously, I rename it on the server side. Can an attacker use it to conduct an XSS attack?

I show images in this way:

```
<img src="image_from_user.jpg" />
```

And videos in this way:

```
<video src="video_from_user.jpg" />
```

Comment: "Can something users upload be used in {type} attack?" yes, it all depends on your server-side application, and whether they can bend it to deliver HTML to load e.g. JavaScript from a file with a .jpg ending. The problem is not the way you embed the images (videos), but the way these files can be exploited.

Comment: It is important that you know your infrastructure better than anyone else. client-side or server-side. Attackers (can and will) study your environment to take control over it if you are unable to do so. What you mention is not vulnerable to XSS if properly escaped. Is `<video src="$img" />`vulnerable? no words.

Comment: @tungsten as I wrote, I rename the filename on server side.

Comment: @Bob I just created a extensionless file named "<script>alert(0);</script>", you are concerned this will be treated as valid javascript?

Comment: To be straight it is **impossible** for an attacker to successfully perform a XSS if its not in the right content-type and **impossible** if its in plain-text, img/jpg and img/png are a wrong formats for XSS. what do you mean with renaming?

Comment: @tungsten I rename the filename. For example, if they upload a file called "<script>alert(1).jpg", I rename it with a random string (randomstring.jpg).

Comment: IF they upload `<script>alert(1).jpg` it will be treated as a valid filename but not a valid javascript-code and the output depends on what content-type the site is supporting.

Comment: If I upload `<script>alert(0).jpg` and I'll click it with opening the the source-code, I will see an image unless the file is modified and your site is rendering it as a html-file instead of a jpg/png.